# In Image processing after applying the preprocessing technique, why do we need to de-process the images for the further computation of the image

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, conv-neural-network

Actually, I was working on a guided project on (neural style transfer) in which I came across the concept of preprocessing and then deprocessing of the image. It will be great if anyone can help me in understanding this concept.

```
  from torchvision import transforms as T

def preprocess(img_path,max_size = 500):
  image = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')

  if max(image.size) > max_size:
    size = max_size
  else:
    size = max(image.size)

  img_transform = T.Compose([
                             T.Resize(size),
                             T.ToTensor(),
                             T.Normalize((0.485, 0.456, 0.406), (0.229, 0.224, 0.225))
  ])

  image = img_transform(image)
  image = image.unsqueeze(0)
  return image
```

....

```
# Deprocess image 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def deprocess(tensor): 

  image = tensor.to('cpu').clone()
  image = image.numpy()
  image = image.squeeze(0) #(1,3,224,224) -> (3,224,224)
  image = image.transpose(1,2,0) #(3,224,224) -> (224,224,3)
  image = image*np.array([0.229, 0.224,0.225])+np.array([0.485,0.456,0.406])
  image = image.clip(0,1)

  return image 

content_d = deprocess(content_p)
style_d = deprocess(style_p)
print("Deprecess content :",content_d.shape)
print("Deprocess style :",style_d.shape)

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize = (20,10))
ax1.imshow(content_d)
ax2.imshow(style_d)
```

[Code Image for preprocessing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxekG.png)

[Code Image for deprocessing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acq2G.png)

I would like to know that can we perform further computation of image by just preprocessed image without actually deprocessing it ?

Comment: IMO this is a terminology created by the author of this piece of code. Nothing "classical". Scrutinize the sequence of transformations applied.

Comment: The question is rather vague.. what do you need to understand specifically? Also, be aware that you tagged it with "Tensorflow" while it's a PyTorch code.